# Excel match cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I would like to match the two tables as follows:

**Table 1**

| Project | Staff |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B, CD, E |
| 2 | B, E, X |

**Table 2**

| Staff | Office |
| --- | --- |
| A | NY |
| B | CA |
| CD | ON |
| E | NY |
| X | FL |

I would like to add a column to the Table 1 as below, after matching.

**Table Results**

| Project | Staff | Office |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B, CD, E | NY, CA, ON, NY |
| 2 | B, E, X | CA, NY, FL |

Would you mind to teach me how to do it with Excel or any other free tool?  Many thanks.

Comment: There are questions on here doing this, have a look.

Comment: Some duplicate question included on the top. Note that if you have even got access to the beta-channel of ms365 insiders, you could even opt to use `TEXTSPLIT()` instead of `FILTERXML()`.

Comment: In the **Office** column of Table 1, use: `=BYROW( B2:B3, LAMBDA(a, TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, UNIQUE( LOOKUP(FILTERXML( "<m><s>" & SUBSTITUTE( a, ", ", "</s><s>" ) & "</s></m>", "//s" ),tOffices[Staff],tOffices[Office]) ) ) ) )` where B2:B3 is Staff Column of the Table 1. I added UNIQUE to remove duplicates in the output, assuming that would be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Sheets and Google Apps Script this would work.
Given the following input.

| Rows | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Project | Staff |  |
| 2 | 1 | A, B, CD, E |  |
| 3 | 2 | B, E, X |  |
| 4 | Staff | Office |  |
| 5 | A | NY |  |
| 6 | B | CA |  |
| 7 | CD | ON |  |
| 8 | E | NY |  |
| 9 | X | FL |  |

the following script

```js
function matchTables(){
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    // get sheet by the name of your sheet
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("my-sheet");

    // get the cells containing your table
    // start in  2nd row, 1st col for 2 rows and columns
    const tab1Body = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 2, 2);
    const tab2Body = sheet.getRange(5, 1, 5, 2);
    // target cells for new column
    const newColumnRange = sheet.getRange(2, 3, 2, 1);

    const staffToOffice = tab2Body.getValues();
    // each staff must have one or zero offices otherwise some adjustments need to be done
    const mapStaffOffice = new Map();
    staffToOffice.forEach(row => {
        // map staff to office
        // e.g. A => NY
        mapStaffOffice.set(row[0], row[1]);
    })

    // get values of tab1
    const projects = tab1Body.getValues();
    const newColumn = [];
    projects.forEach(project => {
        const staffStr = project[1];
        const staffMembers = new String(staffStr).split(", ");

        const projectStaffOffices = [];
        staffMembers.forEach(member => {
            if(!mapStaffOffice.has(member)){
                Logger.log(`Ǹo office found for member of staff ${member}.`)
            }
            // get office for this particular staff member
            else projectStaffOffices.push(mapStaffOffice.get(member));
        })
        // done. all offices for this project have been found
        // first row of the new column is created, separate them with , and add to new column
        newColumn.push([projectStaffOffices.join(", ")]);
    });

    // done. all projects are processed. now write the new colum
    newColumnRange.setValues(newColumn);
    // set heading
    sheet.getRange(1, 3).setValue("Office");
  }
```

will produce this output:

| Rows | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Project | Staff | Office |
| 2 | 1 | A, B, CD, E | NY, CA, ON, NY |
| 3 | 2 | B, E, X | CA, NY, FL |
| 4 | Staff | Office |  |
| 5 | A | NY |  |
| 6 | B | CA |  |
| 7 | CD | ON |  |
| 8 | E | NY |  |
| 9 | X | FL |  |

This was tested on Google Sheets and does work.

#### Input

[image: Input in Google Sheets]

#### Output

[image: Output in Google Sheets]

You only need to go to `Extensions -> Apps Script`.
[image: Navigation to Google Apps Script]

And then paste the code in there
[image: Code in Google Apps Script Editor]